In v8 of highcharts implemented multiple highcharts in a single view but not working in the upgraded version GetHighchartsJS
How to replace
@Html.Highsoft().GetHighchartsJS(chart, "Grid"+i);

in the latest version of highcharts as this is not supported anymore.
        chart.ID = "Grid" + i;
        var renderedHtml = new HighchartsRenderer(chart).RenderHtml();
        @Html.Raw(renderedHtml);

This is not working for me in 11.4.7 version of highcharts.
Trying to load multiple highcharts in a single view

You can try using the HighchartsRenderer.GetJavascript() method and it should work fine.

thanks @jedrzejruta it worked with GetJavascript()
